# How to get rows from multiple values of the same column

Tags: android, android-sqlite

With this statment, I get get one row where column `MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID = 16`:

```
    String[] stringArray = {"16"};
    final Cursor mCursor = getContentResolver().query(
            MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, // Uri
            new String[]{                                 // String[] projection (columns)
                    MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART,
                    MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ARTIST,
                    MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ARTIST,
                    MediaStore.Audio.Albums.NUMBER_OF_SONGS,
                    MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_KEY
            },
            MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID + "=?",           // String selection
            stringArray,                                  // String[] selectionArgs
            null,                                         // sortOrder
            null                                          // CancellationSignal
    );
```

Now how can I get multiple rows where the same column has multiple values e.g. `MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID = 16,25,24,30,...etc`?

Something like this?

```
String[] stringArray = {"16","25","24","30","14","31","28","23","17","16","13"}; 
final Cursor mCursor = getContentResolver().query(
        MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, // Uri
        new String[]{                                 // String[] projection (columns)
                MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART,
                MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ARTIST,
                MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ARTIST,
                MediaStore.Audio.Albums.NUMBER_OF_SONGS,
                MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_KEY
        },
        MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID + "=?",           // String selection
        stringArray,                                  // String[] selectionArgs
        null,                                         // sortOrder
        null                                          // CancellationSignal
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the operator IN:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp

```
final Cursor mCursor = getContentResolver().query(
        MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, // Uri
        new String[]{                                 // String[] projection (columns)
                MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART,
                MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ARTIST,
                MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ARTIST,
                MediaStore.Audio.Albums.NUMBER_OF_SONGS,
                MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_KEY
        },
        MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID + " IN(?,?)",           // String selection
         new String[]{"16","25"},                                  // String[] selectionArgs
        null,                                         // sortOrder
        null                                          // CancellationSignal
);
```

Hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your mSelectionClause `MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID + "=?",` is incorrect.

[Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html) states that you need one "?" for each replaced argument.